# How to display WP Google Map Pro in single page dynamically?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I am using WP Google Map Pro plugins http://www.flippercode.com/ for my site to display list of stores and places. I wanna display map for custom post type I am using this code.

```
$maptext = '';
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wpgmp_metabox_latitude', true) != '') {
    $locationlat = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wpgmp_metabox_latitude', true);
    $locationlong = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wpgmp_metabox_longitude', true);
    $maptext.= '[[display_map width="100%" height="210" zoom="15" language="en" map_type="ROADMAP" map_draggable="true" marker1="';
    $maptext.= $locationlat;
    $maptext.= ' | ';
    $maptext.= $locationlong;
    $maptext.= ' | ' . get_the_title() . '"]]';
    echo do_shortcode($maptext);
    }
```

But output comes only shortcode like 
[display_map width="100%" height="210" zoom="15" language="en" map_type="ROADMAP" map_draggable="true" marker1="27.7172453 | 85.3239605 | Pizza"]

do_shortcode is not working or my code have some error i dont get it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will have to first add the short code with `add_shortcode` and use it via `do_shortcode`. More about add_shortcode https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug it due to [[ in $maptext.

```
$maptext = '';
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wpgmp_metabox_latitude', true) != '') {
    $locationlat = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wpgmp_metabox_latitude', true);
    $locationlong = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wpgmp_metabox_longitude', true);
    $maptext.= '[display_map width="100%" height="210" zoom="15" language="en" map_type="ROADMAP" map_draggable="true" marker1="';
    $maptext.= $locationlat;
    $maptext.= ' | ';
    $maptext.= $locationlong;
    $maptext.= ' | ' . get_the_title() . '"]';
    echo do_shortcode($maptext);
    }
```

Thank you for your support.